# Return SQL table in sequence, duplicates and all.

Tags: sql, list, duplicates, distinct, sequence

This is seemingly a trivial question on SQL but one that has frustrated me for days. Suppose I have a SQL table on currency rates which I am trying to extract. The query I am trying to pass is:

```
SELECT AsAtDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode, Value 
from tblFX
where FromCurrencyCode = 'USD'
and ToCurrencyCode in ('HKD', 'HKD', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'GBP','EUR')
and AsAtDate = '2018-04-24'
```

I want the outcome as a table with the exact sequence as the ***ToCurrencyCode*** I pass in. However, SQL always return the distinct values by default.

```
SQL table output: 
AsAtDate    FromCurrencyCode    ToCurrencyCode  Value
2018-04-24        USD                 EUR      0.818699
2018-04-24        USD                 GBP      0.716101
2018-04-24        USD                 HKD      7.846950
```

There are some solutions that returns only the duplicates in SQL but what I want is the table return in the exact sequence as the list I passed in, inclusive of both unique and duplicates fields. Is there a way to do this in SQL? Thanks guys.

```
Desired SQL table output: 
AsAtDate    FromCurrencyCode    ToCurrencyCode  Value
2018-04-24        USD               HKD         7.846950
2018-04-24        USD               HKD         7.846950
2018-04-24        USD               EUR         0.818699
2018-04-24        USD               HKD         7.846950
2018-04-24        USD               GBP         0.716101
2018-04-24        USD               EUR         0.818699
```

Comment: "However, SQL always return the distinct values by default." - it doesn't return the distinct rows, it returns the rows where the criteria evaluates to true. "where x in ('a' , 'a')" is the same as  "where x = 'a' or x = 'a'". For your needs, a seperate table might help, but it does depend on the input table (e.g. is for every date only 1 tocurrencycode)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... A database is not an Excel sheet. Let me enlighten:

- The SQL standard defines what the `IN` operator does: it's a "set operator" that returns true if an element belongs to the set. Now, including the same value multiple times in the set doesn't do anything extra. Internally the database will remove the duplicate ones right away.
- SQL specifies `SELECT` does not return rows in any specific order by default. If you need a specific order you need to specify it using `ORDER BY`. You cannot ask something like: "Please return the rows in exactly the same order they were inserted". Nope, I'm sorry but that's not SQL.

To get the result you want, you'll need to get the bare rows from the database and *massage* them in your application to look like what you want.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to know if your table allows duplicates regard to the columns that you're retrieving (AsAtDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode, and Value). But due to the purpose of the table, which is store the currency rate of each date, the first three columns actually conform the primary key of the table, so duplicates aren't allowed when return them.

In summary, it's not possible return duplicates in your scenario.

Comment: Why would you assume there even is a PK.. and still, offcourse you can get a result with duplicates: just union some results, or join them with a table with duplicate values for instance...